# HI i'm trying to change these texts on functions.php and i can't, only the first text change, but the second "Detalles de facturación" stay the same

Tags: php, woocommerce

HI i'm trying to change these two texts on functions.php and i can't, only the first text change, but the second "Detalles de facturación" stay the same. any suggestion?, all this code its on the file functions.php on woocommerce -> wordpress.

```
 function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
       switch ( $translated_text ) {
         case 'Cart & Checkout' :
           $translated_text = __( 'Ver carrito', 'woocommerce' );
         break;
         case 'Detalles de facturación' :
           $translated_text = __( 'Datos del cliente', 'woocommerce' );
         break;
            }
         return $translated_text;
       }
    
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

---

**Edit**: I have tried using `str_replace()` as follows:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('Detalles de facturación', 'Detalles del cliente', $text);
    return $text;
}                                                                                           
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

But it didn't work and the issue persist.

Comment: Have you tried using a step-debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically rewriting a function that already exists.

You can easily replace strings with str_replace.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php